# PHP object is not behaving like an object

Tags: php, json, string, object, curl

I am making a JSON request in PHP using curl. I have stored the response in a variable called `$registerCompany` and printing it out on the screen to see what has come back, I get the following response by printing my variable

```
{
resultCode: "duplicate",
result: {
isValid: true,
referenceKey: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
},
success: false
}
```

I know this is an object when I try to get its properties like `$registerCompany->resultCode` I get the following error:

> Trying to get property 'resultCode' of non-object

What is wrong here, can anyone help please

Here is my PHP code

```
function enquiry_company($data) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
          CURLOPT_URL => "hidden",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "content-type: application/json",
                "x-api-key: hidden"
              ],
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;

}


$api_data = [
            "identityNumber" => 123456789,
            "commercialRecordNumber" => 123456789,
            "commercialRecordIssueDateHijri" => 01-01-2000,
            "phoneNumber" => 00000000000,
            "extensionNumber" => 0,
            "emailAddress" => mail@mail.com,
            "managerName" => 'Manager',
            "managerPhoneNumber" => 000000000,
            "managerMobileNumber" => 000000000,
        ];

$registerCompany = enquiry_company($api_data);
echo $registerCompany;
$registerCompany = json_decode($registerCompany, true);
$registerCompany = (object) $registerCompany;
echo $registerCompany->resultCode;
```

Thank you

Comment: The main problem I see is that is not JSON (the keys aren't quoted). Can you please show your actual code including how you're _"printing your variable"_

Comment: @Phil I have add the full code now

Comment: Just change it to `$registerCompany = json_decode($registerCompany);` without the `true` as that explicitly asks for the JSON to be decoded into an **array**

Comment: Next time, try reading the manual so you know what each argument does ~ http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Change `registerCompany->resultCode;` to `registerCompany['resultCode']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you get back an array use `$registerCompany = json_decode($registerCompany)`, this will output an object.

if you did `$registerCompany = json_decode($registerCompany, true)` this will give you an array rather than an object.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thank you @Eli but it is working like an array but I want it to work like an object.. not a big issue but I had it working before, but I lost it all previous work. doing this again... thank you

Comment: Amjad Have you read @Eli answer? That's the reason why you are getting an array instead of an object. Have you followed the link? The first example is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your response is an array

first convert your array into an object to do that

```
$registerCompany = (object)$registerCompany;
```

then here you go your array is now an object and can be access

```
echo $registerCompany->resultCode;
```

Comment: @Amjad you should not need to _"trick"_ anything. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use `gettype` to see what type of variable you have in the first place.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

From there, you have three possibilities.  One is that it's a string.  If it's a string, that means it's in JSON format.  That means you need to JSON decode the format so it will work. See [Eli's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52250492/1713620) answer for that.

Two, it's in array form.  In that case, use beginner's answer and type cast it to an object with `(object) $variableName;`